# ibatis.net datetime and dynamic sql

Tags: sql, dynamic, ibatis.net

how can i test if a property of type dateTime contains value on dynamic sql statement with ibatis.net 
my mapping file is as follow, but it does not work

```
<select id="Select" resultMap ="CongeResult" parameterClass="Conge">
  SELECT * FROM Conge
  <dynamic prepend="WHERE">
    <isGreaterThan property="StartDate" compareValue="01/01/0001 00:00:00">
      START_DATE >= #StartDate#
    </isGreaterThan>        
  </dynamic>
</select>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the Date/Time value in ISO 8601 format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.
Most parsers will correctly parse that string representation.
Your value will be parsed if you type:

```
compareValue="0001-01-01 00:00:00"
```